# Apache2 connections issues

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

Having issues with some website I want to host.  One is an owncloud server that is hosted on my physical machine (port 443) and I have another on a virtualbox guest (port 80).

I have successfully navigated to them internally, but have only successfully connected to them one time over the internet. Now all my attempts to connect give me unable to connect. So I know they are at least partially configured correctly...

I also have a VPN server running on a virtualbox guest (port 8080) and have no problems connecting to it over the internet. Because of this, I'm pretty sure it is an apache configuration issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

These are the only errors in the apache logs:

```
(EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00549: Failed to resolve server name for 10.1.1.9 (check DNS) -- or specify an explicit ServerName
[Tue Jul 26 12:41:02.431334 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1538] AH01909: server.rowell:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jul 26 12:41:02.431418 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1538] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 26 12:41:02.431422 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1538] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Jul 26 12:48:15.217990 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1538] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 26 12:48:16.331568 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 13985] AH01909: server.rowell:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jul 26 12:48:16.383286 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 13986] AH01909: server.rowell:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jul 26 12:48:16.385210 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13986] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 26 12:48:16.385221 2016] [core:notice] [pid 13986] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: The vhost(s) are obviously not properly configured.

Comment: It is impossible to help without seeing the actual configuration.

Comment: Please paste the virtual host configuration of both physical and virtualbox machine

Comment: Yes, Rui is correct that the vhosts are not configured correctly (add a serverName directive to fix) but this would not prevent you from connecting. The latter is probably a dns/network/firewall issue and very unlikely to be anything to so with the Apache config - but without seeing the full httpd config, its impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

If your virtualbox guest has NAT virtual network?

Change it to the bridged and make sure that your router is properly forwarded TCP:80 to the VirtualBox guest IP address in your home network.